# "java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Map"

Tags: elasticsearch

```
PUT my-index-000001
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "strings_as_keywords": {
          "match_mapping_type": "string",
          "mapping`enter code here`": {
            "type": "text",
            "norms": false,
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I would expect that this should create and index. If you can    help me I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: Fixed: I just need to add "mapping name" .

Comment: You've put the error that you're facing in the title of your question. For readibility's sake, it's always a good idea to add all the information in your question's body as well. This helps reviewers and future readers and makes your post more valuable!